# What is better for the performance CollectionUtils.isEmpty() or collection.isEmpty()

Tags: java, performance, collections

What is better for the performance if you already know that the collection isn’t null.
Using `!collection.isEmpty()` or `CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(collection)` from the Apache Commons lib?

Or isn’t there any performance difference?

Comment: Where does `CollectionUtils` come from?

Comment: `!collection.isEmpty()`, although I'd doubt that it makes a noticeable difference.

Comment: I'm sure by the time you get to the point where that is your main performance issue, you won't have to ask this question.

Comment: Before asking which method gives better performance, have you made sure you have a bottleneck in this particular place in your program?

Comment: @RealSkeptic no I was just wondering if there is any difference.

Comment: If you don't know you have a performance problem because you measured it, it is highly likely you are just guessing even if you are an expert in performance tuning.  Do you know this is a problem?  If not I would do what you believe is the simplest and clearest.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The code of CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty (assuming we are talking about Apache Commons here)...

```
public static boolean isEmpty(Collection coll)
{
    return ((coll == null) || (coll.isEmpty()));
}

public static boolean isNotEmpty(Collection coll)
{
    return (!(isEmpty(coll)));
}
```

...so, not really a difference, that one null check will not be your bottleneck ;-)

Comment: So the point of the method isn't to be fast, but to skip an explicit null check.

Comment: Seems like, yes. You can throw any collection in there, including null, without having to worry about NPEs.

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are correct, but just to be sure about it:

Why do you care at all? Does your application have a performance problem; and careful profiling pointed to that method; so you are looking for alternatives?

Because ... if not ... then it could be that we are looking at
[PrematureOptimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

And one other aspect: if "java standard libraries" provide a feature; I would always prefer them over something coming from an "external library". 
Of course, ApacheCommons is quite commons nowadays; but I would only add the dependency towards it ... if all my other code is already using it.

Comment: I think the standard library argument is a good one in general. It's not even necessarily the overhead of having another dependency (after all, you might use the library in other parts of your projects anyway), it's more a question of "when someone reads the code, first they need to be familiar with this library". The fewer pre-requisites your code mandates from readers, the better.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is negligible (extra null check), all calls can be easily inlined even by C1 compiler. In general you should not worry about performance of such simple methods. Even if one of them is twice slower it's still blazingly fast compared to the rest code of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Collection.isEmpty as CollectionUtils which is defined in apache libs is indirectly going to use the collection.isEmpty() method.

Although no noticable difference present in both of them, It's just that

`CollectionUtils.isEmpty` is `NullSafe` and as you say that you know that collection is not empty , so Both are equally Good (Almost)

Answer (score 0):

With the following program you can see the clear results with 1000 Integer in the List. 
Note: time is in milliseconds

collection.isEmpty is almost 0 milliseconds

CollectionsUtils.isNotEmpty take 78 milliseconds

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i<1000; i++)
                list.add(i);

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                list.isEmpty();
            long endTime   = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime = endTime - startTime;
            System.out.println(totalTime);


            long startTime2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
            CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(list);
            long endTime2   = System.currentTimeMillis();
            long totalTime2 = endTime2 - startTime2;
            System.out.println(totalTime2);
        }
```

Comment: it probably picked up some JIT or memory allocation unrelated to the method itself.